# Android bogus span encoding crash

Tags: java, android

I have an issue in my android application, application crashes from the main activity and the error message is

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: bogus span encoding 17831
    at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:802)...
```

this happens not on the all devices, as i can reproduce the error occurs frequently on nexus 5 android version 5.1.1, and also on samsung android version 5.1.1 the error exists.

I have researched a lot but no solution. It seems it was an android 4.0.* version issue but was fixed in latest android versions.

Can anyone help to find the problem?

Thanks

The expanded error message is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: bogus span encoding 17831
    at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:802)
    at android.text.TextUtils$1.createFromParcel(TextUtils.java:679)
    at android.os.Parcel.readCharSequence(Parcel.java:1606)
    at android.os.Parcel.readCharSequenceArray(Parcel.java:1823)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2185)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:755)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:932)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:255)
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a character not recognized in your app.

If you check the android source code, http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/text/TextUtils.java

The exception is set at line 715 of the  `public  CharSequence createFromParcel(Parcel p) {` Method.

Check the spans in your program to see if there is a problem.

Comment: And how check the spans, e.g. I have an $ such kind of character in a string.xml. Can this cause a problem?

Comment: @AniKarapetyan Did you figure out what caused this issue? I am now seeing the same issue in my application but I can't find what's wrong. I'd really appreciate if you could let me know if you found a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was able to figure out the issue. I have a model in my application which fields are filled from the json response and my model implements serializable and parcelable interfaces. I annotated my model fields with the SerializedName("json_field_name") method.

Except of the json fields I included other fields in my model as well. And in some point when I extracted the data from the json with gson library and have no data for the custom fields that I specified in the model (not json fields) I got this error.

For me the issue is fixed by removing the objects from the model which are not exist in json.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same error. I missed a variable in constructor of parcelable .

You should add all your variables in constructor of pogo class which is parcelable.

```
 protected your_class_name(Parcel in) {
    var1= in.readString();
    var2= in.readString();
    var3= in.readString();

}
```

Hope that helps.